# How to determine domain and range of a function?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to practice questions on domain and range and how it affects the graph whether it is or odd, I realized a relationship in some questions but I'm not certain on whether or not they are correct. My thoughts were that for all odd powers or roots, the domain is all real numbers (there isn't any proof of this for me besides a couple of YouTube videos that I used to help guide me).

Basically, I'm trying to understand how domains and ranges are affected pertaining to the questions below. (This is not for an assignment, this is just my own personal study).

What is the domain and range of the functions below, outline with steps?

$$ f(x)=x^{1/4} \tag{1}$$

$$ f(x)=x^{1/5} \tag{2}$$

$$ f(x)=x^4 \tag{3}$$

$$ f(x)=x^5 \tag{4}$$

$$ f(x)=x^{-3} \tag{5}$$

$$ f(x)=x^{-1/3} \tag{6}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In general, finding the domain and range of any function, for example to find the domain of $f(x)=\log_x(x^3)+\arcsin(x^3-1)$ will require you to have an understanding of what the domain of $\log$ and $\arcsin$, and will also require some properties to be known about the functions used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^{2}$ has a range of zero and the positive real numbers and the same is true for all even powers $x^{2n}$
The same is true for the square root of x and other dyadic fraction exponents $x^{\frac{1}{2n}}$
Any odd power of x can be written as an even power times x. Even powers are always positive but x takes in all possible values so odd powers have a range of all real numbers
$x^{-1}$ also ranges between all real numbers
$x^{-3}$ cubes to $x^{-1}$ which means that $x^{-3}$ has to be negative for all negative inputs. This logic can be applied to all odd roots.

When looking for the range, you should always start with the numerator of the fraction. $x^{2/3}=\left({x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)^{2}$ which must be positive.